# How to dynamically change font size in UI to always be the same width in JavaFX?

Tags: css, user-interface, javafx, dynamic, fxml

What I am trying to do is create a label in fxml, using Scenebuilder, which updates its font size to always ensure that the content of the label is the same size.

Some background info is that I am using an `AnchorPane`, which is maximized and non-resizable.

I do not need the height of the text to be the same--just the width.  Also, I would only like to resize *if it is too big to fit*. So if the label is only 1 letter, I do not want it to be a giant single letter.  I only have rudimentary ideas, of which some pseudocode is below.  Thanks!

```java
lengthOfLabel = menuLabel.getText().length();

if(lengthOfLabel > numOfCharsThatCanFitInWidth){
    menuLabel.setStyle("-fx-font-size: " + (int) (someConstant/lengthOfLabel) + ";")
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use temp `Text` object to measure text size, and scale the font if it doesn't fit. Something like this:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    //maximum width of the text/label
    private final double MAX_TEXT_WIDTH = 400;
    //default (nonscaled) font size of the text/label
    private final double defaultFontSize = 32;
    private final Font defaultFont = Font.font(defaultFontSize);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        final TextField tf = new TextField("Label text goes here");

        final Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.setFont(defaultFont);
        lbl.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            //create temp Text object with the same text as the label
            //and measure its width using default label font size
            Text tmpText = new Text(newValue);
            tmpText.setFont(defaultFont);

            double textWidth = tmpText.getLayoutBounds().getWidth();

            //check if text width is smaller than maximum width allowed
            if (textWidth <= MAX_TEXT_WIDTH) {
                lbl.setFont(defaultFont);
            } else {
                //and if it isn't, calculate new font size,
                // so that label text width matches MAX_TEXT_WIDTH
                double newFontSize = defaultFontSize * MAX_TEXT_WIDTH / textWidth;
                lbl.setFont(Font.font(defaultFont.getFamily(), newFontSize));
            }

        });
        lbl.textProperty().bind(tf.textProperty());

        final AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane(lbl, tf);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(tf, 0d);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(tf, 0d);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(tf, 0d);


        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, MAX_TEXT_WIDTH, 200));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Note that `tmpText.getLayoutBounds()` returns the bounds that do not include any transformations/effects (if these are needed, you'll have to add text object to temp scene and calculate its bounds in parent).

[image: Text fits]
[image: Text fits, again]
[image: Text scaled down]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!  Followup question.  If I want the vertical position of the text to stay the same, would I have to bind the y position of the label to the size, or is there an attribute that I can change to vertically center.  (Seems like the y position refers to the top of the label, so the smaller text squishes up to the top)  Regardless, thanks!

Comment: You can use bindings, but it's easier to just set the height of the label and align the text inside however you want: set the height (choose preferred height yourself) `lbl.setPrefHeight(50);`; to center text vertically: `lbl.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);` or, to align it to bottom edge: `lbl.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);`. Of course, if the height of the label is already constrained you don't need to set it explicitly.

Comment: It doesnt work for me, because I set the default font in css. Every time I change the text value of the label, the ScenePulseListener overrides the font I have just set. Implies that the font is always the one specified in css. Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: @SuperSmartWorld In that case, you should use inline styles (they take precedence over the styles defined in css files):
`lbl.setStyle("-fx-font-size: " + newFontSize + "px;");`

Comment: @Guest21 thanks for the advice. I solved it by binding the fontProperty to the font of another label (also defined in css). And then unbinding the proprety when I change the font size again. Using the inline styles should work as well, and is probably a little neater.